# jQuery Slider - Easing effects / Reversing Animations

Tags: jquery, slider, easing

I want to make my slider have several elements fly in and then fly out.

My problem is that the fly out effects are fine, but no matter what I do I cannot get the next slides flyin to work properly.

Here is the jquery for the animation/slide change:

```
                    $active.children('h3, .slide-desc').animate({ 
                        right: 970, 
                        easing: 'easeInOutExpo'
                    }, 1800);
                    $active.children('.slider-button').delay(100).animate({ 
                        right: 970, 
                        easing: 'easeInOutExpo'
                    }, 1800);
                    $active.children('.slide-bg').delay(200).animate({ 
                        left: 970, 
                        easing: 'easeInOutExpo'
                    }, 1200);

                    $next.delay(1400).fadeIn(settings.animationDuration, function () {
                        $active.children('.slide-bg, h3, .slide-desc, .slider-button').css({"left":"","right":""});
                        $active.hide();
                        current = next;
                        $active = $next;
                        animating = false;
                    });
```

I've tried duplicating active and reversing the animation (while making the containing LI visible and pushing the elements to the left off screen) but those animations seem to take place during the period when animation shouldn't be occuring.

Anyone have any examples or ideas of what I should be doing (jQuery noob)?

Comment: try to make your question brief and you explanation small and sharp. you will get more attention...

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out..

```
$next = slides.eq(next);

                    $active.children('h3, .slide-desc').animate({ 
                        left: "-970px", 
                        easing: 'easeOutExpo'
                    }, 1700);
                    $active.children('.slider-button').delay(300).animate({ 
                        left: "-970px", 
                        easing: 'easeOutExpo'
                    }, 1700);
                    $active.children('.slide-bg').delay(200).animate({ 
                        right: "-970px", 
                        easing: 'easeOutExpo'
                    }, 1000);

                    $next.children('h3, .slide-desc').delay(500).animate({ 
                        left: 0, 
                        easing: 'easeInOutExpo'
                    }, 1700);
                    $next.children('.slider-button').delay(10).animate({ 
                        left: 0, 
                        easing: 'easeInOutExpo'
                    }, 1700);
                    $next.children('.slide-bg').delay(1300).animate({ 
                        right: 0,
                        easing: 'easeInOutExpo'
                    }, 800, function () {

                        current = next;
                        $active = $next;
                        animating = false;
                    });
```

For the first slide, I use:

```
slides.eq(current).children('h3, .slide-desc, .slider-button').css({"left":"","right":""});
slides.eq(current).children('.slide-bg, .slide-img').css({"left":"","right":""});
```

And to set defaults:

```
slides.children('h3, .slide-desc, .slider-button').css({"left":"-970px","right":""});
slides.children('.slide-bg, .slide-img').css({"right":"-970px","left":""});
```

It's a crap solution, and I haven't adjusted the timing, but it will work until I have someone else do it right.

I think I will stick with not working with jQuery. I'm sure this will kill someone's browser who is running 1-2gigs of ram.